# Can't access LAN from WIFI. Unidentified device en route?

Tags: wireless-networking, network-shares

I have a directory shared on my computer `Optimas-PC`.  The problem is that I want to access that file fom `Optimas-LT`.  `Optimas-LT` is a laptop while `Optimas-PC` is a desktop computer connected via LAN.  For some reason, it wouldn't let me connect to the computer so that I could access the directory I was sharing.  I could access it from the other computers, but I couldn't even get a ping to the computer.

If I ever try to connect to it, I get this:

[image]
I tried mapping the drive an got this.  I assume this unidentified device is the issue.  Can anybody shed some light on the situation?

[image]

For what it counts, I have a Linksys router.  Other than that, we have no other devices.

**EDIT**

Alright, here is all the details:

`Optimas-PC (The Desktop):`

> IPv4 Address :: 192.168.1.107
>
> Subnet Mask  :: 255.255.255.128

`Optimas-LT (The Laptop):`

> IPv4 Address :: 192.168.1.103
>
> Subnet Mask  :: 255.255.255.128

I've not set up anything for the router itself for the most part.  I'll check it out now and edit to reflect the results.  The *Unknown* question mark is something, I'm not sure though, it isn't a second individual device - I know that.

Comment: What is OPTIMAS-LT connected to? What is the top unknown?

Comment: The subnet mask on the Optimas-LT is missing a 255 (it should be 255.255.255.128).  Was that a typo, or how it really is set?

Comment: @Everett :: Sorry, just a typo.  Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is likely that the Laptop is connected wirelessly through an Access Point (one of the question marks you show).  Is the AP (Access Point) acting as a DHCP server for the Laptop?  What is the Laptops IP address?  What is the IP address of the PC?  What are the subnets for each?

The reason I ask all this is because right now my answer is: Your computers are on two different networks.  In order to prove this wrong (or right) I need the answers to the questions I asked.

Comment: Do any of these settings seem promising?  http://i50.tinypic.com/30m4ht0.png

Comment: Whatever you pulled that information out of is an Access Point. It may be a router too, but it is an AP.

Comment: Can these two computers (Laptop and desktop) ping each other?

Comment: Nope, they cannot.  These settings were also located in the Routers Control Panel under *Advanced Wireless Settings*.

Comment: Okay, now we are getting somewhere.  Are these static IP addresses, or is DHCP turned on, on BOTH computers?

Comment: Neither of them are static IPs.

Comment: Now for the big question, is DHCP service turned on, on the question mark box AND the Unknown box connected to the LAN?  If both of those boxes are acting as DHCP servers, there is no route between them, and they are not on the same network even though they are using the same IP address scheme.

Comment: I can't seem to find a second DHCP option for wireless.  There is one though...  There aren't any reservations set though, just so you know:  http://i45.tinypic.com/2u5xnp4.png

Comment: In the picture you just showed me you can set the DHCP server to disabled (it's the top option).  The catch is, you have to have something else being a DHCP server.  I'm only 99.9% sure you do, but could be wrong.  If you do that and I'm wrong you will need to go back to the factory specifications (reset).  If you know how to reset the Access Point (the question mark box) to its initial config, you can turn off the DHCP service like I described.  Understand, I'm going off available info and best guess, and I can't guarantee I'm right at this point.